# How to shift location of circle in this tikz code

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to reduce space between the heading and circle in this code. I also need some suggestions to make this code more efficient

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}    
\def\myrad{3cm}% radius of the circle \def\myang{60}% angle for the arc    
\begin{document}    
\def\myrad{1.5cm}% radius of the circle
\def\myang{45}% angle for the arc

\begin{tikzpicture}
% the origin
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

% the box for deterministic part
\draw [fill=blue!05!white,dashed] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\draw [draw=none,node font=\LARGE] (-4,3) rectangle (4,4) node[midway] 
{Deterministic};

% the circle and the dot at the origin
\draw (O) node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill] {};
\draw [black!25,thick] circle [radius=\myrad];


 % the ``\theta'' arc
\draw  (\myrad,0) coordinate (xcoord) -- 
        node[midway,below] {$r=1$} (O) -- 
       (\myang:\myrad) coordinate (slcoord)
         pic [draw,thick,->,>=stealth,angle radius=1cm,"$\theta$"] {angle = xcoord--O--slcoord};
 % the outer ``s'' arc
\draw (\myrad,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=\myang,radius=\myrad] {};
\node[draw=none,text width=4cm, font=\Large,align=center] at (0.25,-3){$0\leq \boldsymbol{\theta} \leq \pi/4$\vspace{2mm}$x=\cos(\theta_i)$\\$y=\sin(\theta_i)$};        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Your MWE has some errors:

- missing package `amsmat` or `mathtools`
- missing `\end{tikzpicture}`

With adding `tikz` libraries `backgrounds`, `fit`, `positioning` and `scopes` I rewrote your MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{angles, backgrounds, fit, quotes, positioning, scopes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
           node distance = 5mm,
  my angle/.style = {draw, thick, -stealth, 
                     angle radius=1cm,"$\theta$"}
                        ]
\def\myrad{1.5cm}% radius of the circle
\def\myang{45}% angle for the arc
% the origin
\node (C) [circle,draw=red, minimum size=2*\myrad] {};
\node     [circle, inner sep=1pt, fill] {};
% angle
\draw[thick]
    (C.center) -- node[below] {$r=1$} (0:\myrad)    coordinate (A)
               arc (0:45:1.5)               coordinate (B)
               -- cycle;
\draw   pic [my angle] {angle = A--C--B};
% box for deterministic part
\node (D) [above=of C, font=\Large] {Deterministic};

% math
\node (E) [below=of C, font=\Large] {%
    $\begin{aligned}
    0 & \boldsymbol{\theta} \leq \pi/4  \\
    x & = \cos(\theta_i)            \\
    y & =\sin(\theta_i)
    \end{aligned}$};
% background rectangle
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node [draw, dashed, fill=gray!20, inner xsep=11mm,
           fit=(C) (D) (E)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

all positions of image elements are now relative, so you have central control over distances between nodes (by `node distance`) and size of image elements. Above code is probably slightly shorter then in your MWE.

It isn't clear tome, why you have in equation `\theta` in boldface, but not in image. To my opinion you should remove `boldsymbol` in equation. Equation is now in `amsmath` (`mathtools`) environment `aligned`. I you more like to be centered, than you remove ampersands in equation and `aligned` replace with `gathered`.

As you see, pivot of image is circle `C`. Relative to it are then drawn circle "chop" and angle, above it is image title, below is equation. Background rectangle is realyy *background* and is drawn last.

**Addendum:**
Added color to the circle and angle area. Hopefully I understood you correctly :)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, backgrounds, fit, quotes, positioning, scopes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
           node distance = 5mm,
  my angle/.style = {draw, thick, -stealth,
                     angle radius=1cm,"$\theta$"}
                        ]
\def\myrad{1.5cm}% radius of the circle
\def\myang{45}% angle for the arc
% the origin
\node (C) [circle, draw=red, fill=red!10, minimum size=2*\myrad] {};% added fill, color is red!10. you can change color according to your taste/wish
\node     [circle, inner sep=1pt, fill] {};
% angle
\draw[thick, fill=white] % added fill, color is white. you can change color according to your taste/wish
    (C.center) -- node[below] {$r=1$} (0:\myrad)    coordinate (A)
               arc (0:45:1.5)               coordinate (B)
               -- cycle;
\draw   pic [my angle] {angle = A--C--B};
% box for deterministic part
\node (D) [above=of C, font=\Large] {Deterministic};

% math
\node (E) [below=of C, font=\Large] {%
    $\begin{aligned}
    0 & \leq \boldsymbol{\theta} \leq \pi/4  \\
    x & = \cos(\theta_i)            \\
    y & = \sin(\theta_i)
    \end{aligned}$};
% background rectangle
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node [draw, dashed, fill=blue!10, inner xsep=11mm,
           fit=(C) (D) (E)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although I didn't ask this in my original post, is it possible to add different fill colors to two regions, associated with angle, of circle.

Comment: yes, it is possible :). If I understand you, one is color to "chop", one to circle? I will ad this to my answer (soon).

Comment: i added fill option here: \node (C) [circle,draw=red, fill=red!20,minimum size=2*\myrad] {}; Now the only thing left is to add different color to $0\leq\theta\leq \pi/4$ region

Comment: Now its perfect

Comment: @NAASI, if answer is perfect, than you can up-vote it too :) :) :)